# How to get history of transactions for particular Asset in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have tried below code but i am unable to get transaction history for Specific Asset Can any one help me regarding this issue.

@commit(false)

@returns(Order[])

transaction orderHistory {

o String orderNumber

}enter code here

/**
     * Sample transaction
     * @param {org.acme.Block.orderHistory} purchase
     * @transaction
     */ 
    async function orderHistory(transaction) {

```
    const orderNumber = purchase.orderNumber;
    const nativeSupport = purchase.nativeSupport;

    const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.Block.Order')

    const nativeKey = getNativeAPI().createCompositeKey('Asset:org.acme.Block.Order', [orderNumber]);
    console.log(nativeKey);
    const iterator = await getNativeAPI().getHistoryForKey(nativeKey);
    let results = [];
    let res = {done : false};
    while (!res.done) {
        res = await iterator.next();

        if (res && res.value && res.value.value) {
            console.log(res);
            let val = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            if (val.length > 0) {
               results.push(JSON.parse(val));
            }
        }
        if (res && res.done) {
            try {
                iterator.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
```

Comment: Add your model file logic also.

Comment: @commit(false)
@returns(Order[])
transaction orderHistory {
o String orderNumber
}

Comment: @commit(false) @returns(Order[]) transaction orderHistory { o String orderNumber }  @Isha Padalia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hyperledger composer, all the transactions are stored in a Historian Record (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/historian.html). So querying and using the same will resolve your problem. Historian record is an asset defined in the Hyperledger composer namespace.

Historian record is defined as :

```
asset HistorianRecord identified by transactionId {
  o String      transactionId
  o String      transactionType
  --> Transaction transactionInvoked
  --> Participant participantInvoking  optional
  --> Identity    identityUsed         optional
  o Event[]       eventsEmitted        optional
  o DateTime      transactionTimestamp
}
```

You can read more about the Historian Client API which will prove to be useful for you: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/client-historian

Also, read this discussion on history of an asset in composer: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2458